# Can I have ternary in "homepage" in package.json?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, package.json

I need to make api calls, and on production it will be on the same domain as where my app is hosted, so I need to have `"homepage": "."`, in `package.json`.

However, from `localhost` I need to make api calls to the **production** domain. How can I do this with using the "`homepage`" in the `package.json`? This is JSON file, I cannot have ternary operator there.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this problem is solved by having separate configuration files for each one of your environments.

Take a look at [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) for example, or any other [config](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=config) solution.

Comment: Please post example. Thanks.

Comment: Each package comes with its own example.

Comment: For dotenv please.